# What does this while loop means with or operator and condition

Tags: c#, while-loop, timeout, operators, duration

I have while loop from documentation. But I dont know what it exactly does:

```
while (waitForEver || (duration &lt; timeout)){}
```

How should I define "lt" and what value should it have?

I have to get the current status of application.

Comment: `&lt;` is the HTML escape sequence for `<`. Did you paste this code from a browser?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Documentation Mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you copied it from online

Just replace `&lt;` by `<`. The same with `&gt;` and `>`.

Comment: Yes, that is it. It was documentation Error. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

If you pass -1 as the timeout then keep trying forever, otherwise give in after timeout ms